# How does enumerate work with list comprehension using 2 variables (X, Y) in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumerate

I want to create lists of pairs of tuples using list comprehension and the enumerate function, with the code below:

```
array = [10, 5, 2, 3]
array_e = enumerate(array)     
pairs_e = [ [X, Y] for X in array_e for Y in array_e ]
print(pairs_e)
```

My understanding is that array_e is an object containing the following tuples:

(0, 10), (1, 5), (2, 2), (3, 3).

Therefore the pairs_e list should contain lists of pairs of all tuples combinations above according to me (that is what I want to do), but the output is as below:

[[(0, 10), (1, 5)], [(0, 10), (2, 2)], [(0, 10), (3, 3)]]

The list of pairs were created using only the FIRST tuple for X, how about the rest?

How to get the full list of pairs including:

[(1, 5), (2, 2)], [(1, 5), (3, 3)], [(2, 2), (3, 3)], and even [(0, 10), (0, 10)], [(1, 5), (1, 5)] etc?

What is going on?

Comment: `enumerate(array)` is not a list. It can only be iterated once. If you want to iterate it multiple times, make it into a list. `array_e = list(enumerate(array))`.

Comment: Thank you. My understanding is that "enumerate" is an iterator, not a generator.  Generators can only be iterated once and the same is true for some iterators but not all (hence my confusion...) but for "enumerate" it can only be iterated once, I got it now... Also I did make it a list and it works but it seems that this slows down the code a lot and I am interested in making it faster because this shall run with very large arrays. Any idea?